# Hazelcast: connecting to remote cluster

Tags: java, hazelcast

We have a cluster of Hazelcast nodes all running on one remote system (single physical system with many nodes). We would like to connect to this cluster from an external client - a Java application which uses code as below to connect to Hazelcast:

```
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.addAddress(config.getHost() + ":" + config.getPort());

        client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

where, host is the IP of remote and port is 5701.

This still connects to the local host (127.0.0.1). What am I missing?

**Edit:**

If the java client is the only hazelcast app running on the local system, it fails to connect and throws the exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get initial partitions!`

From the logs:

> 14:58:26.717 [main] INFO  c.m.b.p.s.s.HazelcastCacheClient - creating
>   new Hazelcast instance
>
> 14:58:26.748 [main] INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService -
>   HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.1] is STARTING
>
> 14:58:27.029 [main] INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService -
>   HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.1] is STARTED
>
> 14:58:27.061 [hz.client_0_dev.cluster-listener] INFO 
>   com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService -
>   HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.1] is CLIENT_CONNECTED
>
> 14:58:27.061 [hz.client_0_dev.cluster-listener] INFO 
>   c.h.client.spi.ClientClusterService -
>
> Members [5] {     Member [127.0.0.1]:5701     Member [127.0.0.1]:5702
>     Member [127.0.0.1]:5703     Member [127.0.0.1]:5704     Member
>   [127.0.0.1]:5705 }
>
> 14:58:47.278 [main] ERROR c.h.c.spi.ClientPartitionService - Error
>   while fetching cluster partition table!
>
> com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: no further information ... Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: no further information
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>
> at
>   com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.getOrConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:282)
>   ~[BRBASE-service-manager-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
>
> ... 14 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>
> at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:45)
>   ~[BRBASE-service-manager-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na] ...

Comment: Please share your Config file

Comment: There is no config file. The `config` here is an internal class. The host and port are passed as command line arguments to the java client.

Comment: did you try harcoding the address.?
does it still connect to the local host.?

Comment: If client's application is started first, it always fails.

Comment: Server is already running. Client is started next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To connect to the remote cluster, make sure the cluster uses the external IP and not `127.0.0.1`. In our case we have a single physical system, with multiple nodes, with `tcp-ip` mode enabled. The `hazelcast.xml` has the configuration:

```xml
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <!-- This should be external IP -->
    <interface>172.x.x.x</interface>
</tcp-ip>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(host + ":" + port);
HazelcastInstance instance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

Comment: this sounds like you have a firewall problem

Comment: All are in one network within the company LAN. I can telnet to the target host-port.

Comment: That's weird. Can you test a new version like just today released 3.5? Is server and client using the same version?

Comment: What should be settings of the cluster to allow connections from remote? For example, if the remote cluster has tcp-ip enabled with 127.0.0.1 or fixed IPs, will it allow any remote client to connect? Logically, it should not, isn't it? Else it is a security risk.

Comment: The configured IPs are only used in a comparison on requests, if incoming IP is not matching the pre-configured IP(s) the connection is denied. To prevent listening on other IPs you need to set the property "hazelcast.socket.bind.any" to false.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to multiple ip's running Hazelcast as cluster add below to your client config and then instantiate client.

```java
//configure client properties
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
String[] addresses = {"172.20.250.118" + ":" + "5701","172.20.250.49" + ":" + "5701"};
config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(addresses);

//start Hazelcast client
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```