# Hazelcast connect to external address

Tags: java, hazelcast

when i try to connect local cluster with

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
ClientNetworkConfig cnc = clientConfig.getNetworkConfig();
cnc.addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

this works fine.
but by connection to external adress, how `10.0.0.1:5701` i receive

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried:[/10.0.0.1:5701]
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.connectToCluster(ClusterListenerSupport.java:174)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientClusterServiceImpl.start(ClientClusterServiceImpl.java:191)
```

how can i set up HazelcastClient to connect IP `10.0.0.1` ? (programmatically or with xml)

i have already seen [Hazelcast: connecting to remote cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883345/hazelcast-connecting-to-remote-cluster) but i cannot find how to make it programmatically

Comment: Are you sure there's not just a firewall blocking the port 5701?

Comment: @noctarius, yes, i'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a telnet to the IPaddress and port . If telnet fails then you will need to open firewall port if you are providing public IP .

> telnet ip port

Comment: Can you please check the network setup on the computer .. does it have more than one network card  ?